# Angularjs string value or expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

I have a directive which takes a parameter which can either be a string or an expression which resolves into a string. How can I determine whether it's one or the other?

```
// directive code around these lines...

$scope.$watch(attr.param, function() {
  var evaluatedExpr = $parse(attr.param)(scope);
  doSomethingWith(evaluatedExpr);
});

// for a string, I just call
doSomethingWith(attr.param);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to eval a string as an expression use the $scope.$eval method. But, as @ChadRobinson pointed out, this shouldnt be something you need to do in your directive as the expr should probably be evaluated on the parent scope.
As a note to that, unless you are inheriting the parent scope in your directive your expr may not have the information it needs to actually evaluate from within your directive.

```
 $scope.test = function(v){
      var expr =  $scope.$eval(v);
      if(!expr){
        console.log("could not eval, maybe a string... who knows?");
      }else{
        console.log(expr);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How have you defined this parameter in your scope block? Your choice here determines the answer:

`@` - This is a one-way binding, so it *must* be an expression.

`&` - This binds to a method that executes in the parent' scope, so you would be defining a 'getter' in the parent that the child can call. This may be useful if you are writing a generic library and you want the person using your directive to be able to choose what gets passed. In that case, you would expect that caller to perform any `$parse` operations required.

`=` - This makes a two-way binding, which means it must be a property name. It cannot be an expression (or method).

This feeds into your own code example. You are setting a watcher on the parameter. That seems to imply that you're using two-way binding - it wouldn't make sense for a one-way binding because that's only evaluated once. But in that case, you wouldn't call `$parse` because you'd have the raw value to work with, not an expression.

Comment: I don't want to restrict the way the parameter is used (it can be both). It's using `restrict: 'A'` and I obtain the value from `attr.myDirective`.

Comment: You can pass a literal string as an expression. I would do this before I tried to dual task the attribute. Just make it so  the attribute  always evaluates as an expression and users who need a literal string can just put it in quotes.